# Sublime Text 3 Issue - type() function doesnt work

Tags: python-3.x

I do not see any output after using the type(variable name) function. I have tried to use CMD+SHIFT+B and CMD+B commands but I still dont get it. Is there any mistake I am making?

Comment: Did you print it? I need clue. Please give me some codes when you post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `type()` doesn't by default **display** any output to the screen. It takes an input and **returns** the type of that input. To actually see what `type()` is returning, you need to display that output.

```
print(type("""Your code goes here"""))
```